# Select2 doesn't allow dropdown to be unblocked

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

When

```
$("select").select2({});
```

is in the code, javascript doesn't unlock the next dropdown. The problem exist in Firefox. When removed it works like a charm.

http://jsfiddle.net/DcunN/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) this is how you would do it.

```
 $('#dropdown2').select2('enable', false);
```

and

```
  $('#dropdown2').select2('enable', true);
```

You can simplify it to:

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function () {
     $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();
     var val = obj[$(this).val()];
     if (val) {
         $('#dropdown2').append('<option></option>' + obj[$(this).val()]);
     } 
     $('#dropdown2').select2('enable', !val);

 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJn9F/)**

Comment: @isherwood seems like OP is having other issues, scripts not defined or something.. I think this question itself should be closed... :) I have no idea if `select2` is not defined how did he get it to work at all in his code before.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just change attributes. You also have to re-init Select2 to update its element classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/DcunN/9/

```
$("#dropdown1").change(function () {
         $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();

         if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined) {
             $('#dropdown2').removeAttr('disabled').select2();

             ...
```

Comment: yea, when I try to re-init select2 I get this: ypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
 

$("select").select2({

Comment: Dont reinit the dropdown. You have option in select2 itself

Comment: It works perfectly in jsfiddle but in the browser I still get this:TypeError: $(...).removeAttr(...).select2 is not a function
 

$('#dropdown2').removeAttr('disabled').select2();                                        Updated code:http://jsfiddle.net/2eXEL/1/

Comment: @user1029829 first of all dont use removeAttr, use prop instead. But in case of select2 they do all the work for you, you just need to use their options properly. See the example and demo in my answer.

Comment: Still the same error, take a look at the order of js files, maybe they  get attached incorrectly:  http://jsfiddle.net/FxH64/

Comment: TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
 

$('#dropdown2').select2('enable', true)

Comment: @user1029829 do you have select2 plugin included at all. You may want to look at that. If it works in fiddle it has to work if your script inclusion is right.

Comment: It looks like when I put this line: $('#dropdown2').select2('enable', true) anywhere before the .change it works correctly. It shows the error mentioned before only if I put it inside of .change Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see that error. What browser? I suggest looking at PSL's answer instead.